# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 does not use Proxy configuration

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 configured to use a local proxy (squid 3.1.20) with the passthru transport.
However it seems that WSO2 ESB does not use the proxy to retrieve the WSDL URI when creating a proxy based WSDL. It keeps trying to retrive the WSDL URI directly from the remote without going through the proxy every time I click on the "Test URI" Button.

How is it possible to configure WSO2 ESB to use the configured http proxy for all outgoing requests?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try with java start parameters : 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=**hostname** -Dhttp.proxyPort=**portnumber**

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I tried with proxy parameters as java parameters but I have same behavior. By using tcpdump to see traffic sent, I can see that WSO2 still tries to reach the remote server directly without using the provided proxy server.